# solving square congruence with prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I was solving algebras with certain domain and end up with a nice congruence formula, I failed to do some research about how to solve this since I don't know how to describe this problem, so I hope someone could help me out.

Here's the problem:

$$  p^4 \equiv N^2 \space \pmod{4p^2}  $$

where all I know is $N$ will be a given integer that is not prime and $p$ is a prime less than $N$.

I am looking for a specific p that satisfy this equation, for example,

$$7^4 \equiv 21^2 \space (mod \space 4(7^2))$$

If more details are desired, please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Servaes Thanks for reminding me about, just edited it.

Comment: is this used in factoring or cryptographic keys ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Yes! I'm working on some factoring problems and get myself stuck in here..

Comment: For a class? or other purposes.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Not quite for a class. It's just for any prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation you're dealing with is

$$p^4 \equiv N^2 \pmod{4p^2} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Moving $N^2$ to the left and factoring gives that

$$\left(p^2 - N\right)\left(p^2 + N\right) \equiv 0 \pmod{4p^2} \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Since $p$ is a prime, it must divide $p^2 - N$ or $p^2 + N$, with both cases requiring that

$$N = kp  \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

for some integer $k$. Thus, \eqref{eq2} becomes

$$p^2\left(p - k\right)\left(p + k\right) \equiv 0 \pmod{4p^2} \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

Thus,

$$\left(p - k\right)\left(p + k\right) \equiv 0 \pmod{4} \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

If $p = 2$, this requires that $k$ be an even integer, while if $p$ is an odd prime, then any odd integer $k$ will work.

In summary, for a given $N$, any of its prime factors $p$ could work, but with the restrictions that if it's $p = 2$, then \eqref{eq1} is satisfied if $N$ is a multiple of $4$, and if it's an odd prime $p$, then \eqref{eq1} is satisfied if $N$ is an odd integer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @PetaGlz You are welcome. I'm glad I was able to help.